# Does SQL Server Express support FileTable

Tags: sql, sql-server-express, filetable

Does SQL Server Express support filetables? If not, what's the nearest approach to filetables in SQL Server Express?

Answer (score 5):

A quick peek at [Features support by the SQL Server editions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) and a search for `FILETABLE` shows: **yes**, SQL Server **Express** does indeed support file tables

[image]

Comment: thanks mark, but currently under Tables node I just have 'System Tables' and there is no 'File Tables' node. I have Microsoft Sql Server 2012 express